# Can Grease Pencil get light / shadows like a regular mesh?

Tags: grease-pencil

I was wondering if a Grease Pencil layer can get (or generate) light and shadows like a regular mesh ?
Before Grease Pencil, I was achieving this by loading an image sequence as a texture on planes; and this was casting light.

Now that GP exists, it could improve my workflow a lot (no need to export / re-import the animation, setup a material, etc) - but I need to having it interacting with lights...

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

from [Blenderartists](https://blenderartists.org/t/grease-pencil-merge-in-blender-2-8/1120744/85) on August 2018 :

> No. Grease Pencil objects don’t cast shadows or emit light. In fact,
>   there is a need to restore conversion from GP object to curve or
>   meshe.
>
> Currently, a GP stroke or an annotation cannot be converted to a curve
>   or mesh like it works in 2.79.

from developper Antonio Vazquez (antoniov) on 2018-01-10 :

> This is feature in Todo list (integration with Eevee), but it's not a
>   simple thing, so it will be done in future versions 2.8x

Comment: Since then, most remains unchanged but «a GP stroke or an annotation cannot be converted to a **curve or** mesh» should be just «a GP stroke or an annotation cannot be converted to a mesh». Conversion to curve seems to work (and casts the right shadows once Fill type is set to Full and Bevel depth to 0.01)

Comment: Upvote the idea on Blender's Right Click Select : http://blender.community/c/rightclickselect/Vdcbbc/

Answer (score 1):

Realized as visual effects->shadow in current version 2.91.
https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/grease_pencil/visual_effects/shadow.html

Comment: This FX is just a simple drop shadow, which do not react with the light setup of the scene.